inet_pton() giving seemingly random results
I'm trying to learn socket programming in C and I'm currently working on a server that will, hopefully, manage a chat room.
Problem:
Each time I run the program, the inet_pton() function seems to convert the same string into some random address
Here's an example
./server 127.0.0.1 8080
Server address: 127.0.0.1
Server port: 8080
socket(): Success!
213.210.223.158
bind(): error: Address family not supported by protocol
./server 127.0.0.1 8080
Server address: 127.0.0.1
Server port: 8080
socket(): Success!
95.18.21.235
bind(): error: Address family not supported by protocol
./server 127.0.0.1 8080
Server address: 127.0.0.1
Server port: 8080
socket(): Success!
63.123.12.198
bind(): error: Address family not supported by protocol
./server 127.0.0.1 8080
Server address: 127.0.0.1
Server port: 8080
socket(): Success!
216.53.247.216
bind(): error: Address family not supported by protocol
./server 127.0.0.1 8080
Server address: 127.0.0.1
Server port: 8080
socket(): Success!

As a result of the wrong address, the bind function doesn't work since the address given to me by inet_pton is not compatible with the existing socket... Or at least that's how I understand it (?)
I'll paste the entire code later, but here's the important part:
else { // User entered a specific IP address
        int addrfamily = getaddrfamily(addrstr);
        res = malloc(sizeof(struct addrinfo));
        memset(res, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
        if (addrfamily == AF_INET) {
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
            memset(ipv4, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

            // Conversion doesn't seem to work properly...
            inet_pton(AF_INET, addrstr, &(ipv4->sin_addr));

            res->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)ipv4;
            res->ai_family = AF_INET;
            res->ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
            res->ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
            res->ai_addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
            free(ipv4);
        } else if (addrfamily == AF_INET6) {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
            res->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)ipv6;
            res->ai_family = AF_INET6;
            res->ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
            res->ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
            res->ai_addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
            free(ipv6);
        } else {
            printf("error: Invalid address\n");
            free(res);
            return 1;
        }
    }

Explanation:
The user enters an ip address and port number as terminal arguments (it's possible to enter 0 as the address argument to print out a list of possible addresses to choose from), When the user enters a specific address, I want to convert the string into a sockaddr* structure and put it into res->ai_addr (the res structure will be used later on in the code)
Complete code:
/* Server that manages a chat room */

// include necessary libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>

// definitions

// function declarations
void printaddrs(struct addrinfo *res);
void printusage();
int isdig(char c);
int isaddr(char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]);
int isport(char port[6]);
char *strin(FILE *stream);
int getaddrfamily(char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // argv[1] -> address for the server to bind to, if it is 0, print a list of addrs with getaddrinfo()
    // argv[2] -> port for the server to bind to

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~ Argument validity checking - Start~~~~~~~~~~~~
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Not enough arguments\n\n");
        printusage();
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc > 3) {
        printf("Too many arguments\n\n");
        printusage();
        return 1;
    }
    if (strlen(argv[1]) > INET6_ADDRSTRLEN) {
        printf("IP address too long\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (isaddr(argv[1]) == 0) { //  is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address
        printf("Invalid <ip addr> argument\n\n");
        printusage();
        return 1;
    }
    if (strlen(argv[2]) > 6) {
        printf("Port number too long\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (isport(argv[2]) == 0) { //
        printf("Invalid <port> argument\n\n");
        printusage();
        return 1;
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[2], "0") == 0) {
        printf("Argument <port> cannot be 0\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // if <port> is a reserved port number - !!! Be careful with those !!!
    if (strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10) < 1024) {
        printf("CAUTION!\nBe cautious when using reserved port numbers\n");
    }
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~ Argument validity checking - End ~~~~~~~~~~~~

    errno = 0;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // Use both IPv4 and IPv6
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // Use TCP/IP (not UDP)

    char addrstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    strcpy(addrstr, argv[1]);
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "0") == 0) { // User entered '0' as the first argument
        int status = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[2], &hints, &res);
        if (status != 0) {
            printf("getaddrinfo(): error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
            return 1;
        }
        printaddrs(res);
        printf("Select an address to bind to: ");
        char *id = strin(stdin);

        int count = 0;
        for (; res != NULL; res = res->ai_next) {
            if (strtol(id, NULL, 10) == count) {
                if (res->ai_family == AF_INET) {
                    struct sockaddr_in *ipv4;
                    ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr;
                    inet_ntop(res->ai_family, &(ipv4->sin_addr), addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
                } else if (res->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
                    struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6;
                    ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)res->ai_addr;
                    inet_ntop(res->ai_family, &(ipv6->sin6_addr), addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
                } else {
                    printf("error: Choosing an address of an invalid address family is not allowed\n");
                    printf("Terminating...\n");
                    free(id);
                    freeaddrinfo(res);
                    return 1;
                }
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
        free(id);
        if (res == NULL) {
            printf("error: Couldn't find entered id\n");
            freeaddrinfo(res);
            return 1;
        }
    } else { // User entered a specific IP address
        int addrfamily = getaddrfamily(addrstr);
        res = malloc(sizeof(struct addrinfo));
        memset(res, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
        if (addrfamily == AF_INET) {
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
            memset(ipv4, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
            inet_pton(AF_INET, addrstr, &(ipv4->sin_addr));
            res->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)ipv4;
            res->ai_family = AF_INET;
            res->ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
            res->ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
            res->ai_addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
            free(ipv4);
        } else if (addrfamily == AF_INET6) {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
            res->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)ipv6;
            res->ai_family = AF_INET6;
            res->ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
            res->ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
            res->ai_addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
            free(ipv6);
        } else {
            printf("error: Invalid address\n");
            free(res);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Server address: %s\n", addrstr);
    printf("Server port: %s\n", argv[2]);

    // Socket descriptor of the server
    // will listen for incoming client connections
    int serverfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (serverfd == -1) {
        printf("socket(): error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        if (argv[1] == 0) {
            // Free the entire linked list
            freeaddrinfo(res);
        } else {
            // Free just the single addrinfo structure
            free(res);
        }
        return 1;
    }
    printf("socket(): Success!\n");
    char test[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, res->ai_addr, test, res->ai_addrlen);
    printf("%s\n", test);
    if (bind(serverfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        printf("bind(): error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        if (argv[1] == 0) {
            // Free the entire linked list
            freeaddrinfo(res);
        } else {
            // Free just the single addrinfo structure
            free(res);
        }
        return 1;
    }
    printf("bind(): Success!\n");

    printf("Success!\nTerminating...\n");
    if (argv[1] == 0) {
        // Free the entire linked list
        freeaddrinfo(res);
    } else {
        // Free just the single addrinfo structure
        free(res);
    }
    return 0;
}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~ Function definitions ~~~~~~~~~~~~

// prints available addresses to possibly bind to
void printaddrs(struct addrinfo *res) {
    int id = 0;
    char addrstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char ipver[30];
    for (struct addrinfo *p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4;
            ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(ipv4->sin_addr), addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
            strcpy(ipver, "ipv4");
        } else if (p->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6;
            ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(ipv6->sin6_addr), addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
            strcpy(ipver, "ipv6");
        } else {
            strcpy(addrstr, "error: Invalid address family");
            strcpy(ipver, "error: Invalid address family");
        }

        printf("%d|%s\t%s\n", id, ipver, addrstr);
        id++;
    }
}

// prints the 'usage:' message
void printusage() {
    printf("usage:\n./server <ip addr> <port>\n");
    printf("<ip addr> - IPv4 or IPv6 address for the server to bind to (only dots or colons allowed)\n");
    printf("<port> - Port number for the server to bind to\n");
}

// Returns 1 if character c is a digit (0-9)
int isdig(char c) {
    switch(c) {
        case '0':
            return 1;
        case '1':
            return 1;
        case '2':
            return 1;
        case '3':
            return 1;
        case '4':
            return 1;
        case '5':
            return 1;
        case '6':
            return 1;
        case '7':
            return 1;
        case '8':
            return 1;
        case '9':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

// Returns 1 if addr is a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address, otherwise returns 0
int isaddr(char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]) {
    int isipv4 = 0, isipv6 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(addr); i++) {
        // If both dots and colons are present in addr return 0
        if (isipv4 && isipv6)
            return 0;
        if (addr[i] == '.')
            isipv4 = 1;
        else if (addr[i] == ':')
            isipv6 = 1;
        // if character is something other than a digit, dot or colon
        if (isdig(addr[i]) == 0 && addr[i] != '.' && addr[i] != ':')
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

// Returns 1 if number(5 digits) is a valid port number, returns 0 if it's not
int isport(char port[6]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(port); i++) {
        if (isdig(port[i]) == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

// Takes string input from FILE *stream - !!! result must be free()'d !!!
char *strin(FILE *stream) {
    char *str = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;

    int c;
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        c = getc(stream);
        if (stream != stdin) {
            if(c == EOF)
                break;
        } else {
            if(c == EOF || c =='\n')
                break;
        }
        size++;
        str = realloc(str, size * sizeof(char));
        *(str + i) = c;
        i++;
    }
    if (size == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    str[size] = '\0';
    return str;
}

// Returns the address family of a given valid IP address, or -1 if no dots or colons are present
int getaddrfamily(char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(addr); i++) {
        if (addr[i] == '.')
            return AF_INET;
        else if (addr[i] == ':')
            return AF_INET6;
    }
    return -1;
}

I tried googling, searching for solutions, asking chatGPT and nothing worked
I'm allocating and initializing memory for the variables and structures that need it. I have no idea where the problem could be.
I should also mention that it works like a charm if I enter 0 and use getaddrinfo to handle all the "address stuff" for me.
Do you guys have any suggestions?
Thank you all in advance for your answers!

You're assigning a pointer to a field of the res variable and then freeing that same pointer...

I'd move if (isipv4 && isipv6) to the bottom of the loop so you catch both being set to true on the last iteration. Doesn't seem like the issue but still worth fixing.

Compile with -g -fsanitize=address,undefined and re-run the program.  It'll say something like "AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free in main ... file.c:" which is inet_ntop(AF_INET, res->ai_addr, test, res->ai_addrlen); where you use a resource after it's been freed.

In the IPv6 case you not only free the object to which res->ai_addr points before using res, but you don't even set the contents of that object.

Why are you only using getaddrinfo when the user enters 0 as first argument?
